# How open in another tab a link html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `link` href built with html, but this link i will open with left button mouse it will open in the same page, that is the wrong i need to open in other tab, so i want to open in another tab

```
const url = `https://shiene/mk/${number}`
const ref = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + 'Go' + '</a>'
```

i saw others answers but they solved with click button,

i dont know if its possible solve with html or javascript dont care to me
how can i open in other tab?

Comment: Just add `target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"` to the link in your javascript, make sure to get the quotes correctly since you are using single quotes

Comment: maybe try to use the document.createElement method link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a link in a new tab, add `target="_blank"`

```js
    const url = `https://shiene/mk/${number}`
    const ref = "<a href='" + url + "' target=\"_blank\">" + 'Go' + '</a>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add target=“_blank” to the link element and maybe try to use the document.createElement method.
Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement
traget attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/target